# How to populate a javascript "dictionary" by iterating over an array of

Tags: javascript, typescript

edit: Below is a simplified version of what I tried to do. I apologize that it seemed incomplete. I tried to make a minimal reproducible example but my javascript knowledge is too lacking and I thought the problem was equivalent (trivial).
I have an array of endpoints `choices`.
I try to populate a dictionary `data_collection`.
`choices.forEach((choice) => getAllData(choice.value))`
where

```
function getAllData(datapoint)
{
    d3.json(dataroot + datapoint).then((res) => alldata[datapoint] = res);
}
```

I get an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Object'
```

I am now trying all the kind suggestions in the comments and will update as soon as I did all of them.

I've been trying to populate a "dictionary" of data in javascript and index it with a string.

I followed some [simple guide](https://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/javascript-basics-how-to-create-a-dictionary-with-keyvalue-pairs) but I must misunderstand it.

```js
let choices = ["hello", "world", "yeah"]
let data_collection = new Object();

choices.forEach(choice => data_collection[choice] = choice.length);
console.log(data_collection);
```

I get an error of the sort object can't be assigned by string.

Many thanks in advance! Apologies for the absolute newbie question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248655/discussion-on-question-by-olli-how-to-populate-a-javascript-dictionary-by-iter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for, try it.

```
let choices = ["hello", "world", "yeah"]
let data_collection = new Object();

for (let i of choices) {
    data_collection[choices.indexOf(i)] = i;
}

console.log(data_collection);
```

will display this in the console:

```
{0: 'hello', 1: 'world', 2: 'yeah'}
```

Comment: I took this question to be about a Typescript dictionary.. When I attempt to include  your code in my .TS file, ,VSCode gives a red line saying *"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'Object'."*

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, I'd say declare your dictionary properly as a **Map**, like

change

```
 let choices = ["hello", "world", "yeah"]
 let data_collection = new Object();

 choices.forEach(choice => data_collection[choice] = choice.length);
 console.log(data_collection);
```

into

```
 let choices = ["hello", "world", "yeah"]
 let data_collection: Map<string,number> = new Map<string,number>();

 choices.forEach(choice => data_collection.set(choice, choice.length);
 console.log(data_collection);
```

Testing above second fragment, my webkit console output for data_collection looks like this,

[image]